# CSS Transitions for checkbox not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I have this piece of HTML (placed on CSSDesk):

```
<section style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <header style="margin-bottom: 30px;">My checkboxes</header>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
</section>
```

And this piece of CSS, also placed on CSSDesk:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
.checkbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label{
  top: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute; /*otherwise ,,left: x px;" isn't working*/
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: blue;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
   transition: all .5s ease;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  left: 80%;
}
```

Impressed by [Paul Underwood checkboxes](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-style-checkboxes/) I follow his tutorial: [How To Style A Checkbox With CSS](http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css). Unfortunately, transition (I copied in 100% from tutorial) didn't work. And I don;t have any idea why. Here is my entire code, placed in CSS Desk: [CSS Desk Decorative checkboxes](http://cssdeck.com/labs/vqmzfhxc). I will be pleased if anybody decides to help me - thank you in advance. My browser - Opera 25.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to insert `left: 0px` in `.checkbox label{...}` class , because you expect that transition will be applied to transformation in x-Axis. Here is a working snippet.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.checkbox label {
  /*insert next line*/
  left: 0px;
  top: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  /*otherwise ,,left: x px;" isn't working*/
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <header style="margin-bottom: 30px;">My checkboxes</header>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. When I learn from tutorial I always try to copy as little as possible, and in this case it made me some trouble - thank you very much for help :)

Comment: No problem! :) Well, the best way to learn something is to try it out and learn from mistakes.